# Factory contract failing to create - Mix

Tags: solidity, mix

I'm trying to implement factory contracts in Mix but can't get the child to create and return an address. 
I deploy `Factory` but when I try to call the creator function,

```
contracts['Factory'].contract.Create(10)
```

Mix throws:

```
JavaScript  error   14:18:06    web3.js - line 3881 - Uncaught invalid address
```

---

```
contract Gizmo
{
    int public value;
    function Gizmo(int v) {
        value = v;
    }
}

contract Factory
{
    address gizmoAddr;
    function Create(int _value) returns (address) {
        gizmoAddr = new Gizmo(_value);
        return gizmoAddr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an address that you are sending the transaction from

```
contracts['Factory'].contract.Create(10,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:100000});
```

You can change the gas as needed, but 100,000 should be enough for this.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I call the `gizmo` by address in js, e.g `contracts[0x97fea572b69e27ca44475534359d9bb932133fb3].contract.value()`?

Comment: You can't really return a value from an on-chain transaction, so the best way is probably to declare `address constant gizmoAddr` and then just use the ABI to create a new contract object in web3

Comment: Or you can put a function into Factory that lets you call Gizmo without needing to manually use Gizmo's address

Comment: I'm not understanding this.  I need factory to call the gizmo instance after it's created.  I can't declare `gizmoAddr` as constant as it needs to be created dynamically.
Also, to Factory, I added the function:

 `function getGizmoVal() returns (int) { return gizmoAddr.val(); }`

but when I call it with JS responds with a different return value every time. :/

Comment: `function getGizmoVal() constant returns (int)` works correctly

Comment: The `constant` keyword doesn't actually do anything in the contract, btw. It just tells web3 to simulate an execution by default instead of sending a transaction